# Where to store temporary downloaded folder?

Tags: android, file-io, temporary-files

I am trying to download a video from a URL and then watermark it on the client (android and ios- react native app). I don't want my user to access un-watermarked video. I am planning to first download the video in some temporary location and then watermark it. Where should I store the video in android (size of video is around 300 MB max)?
Is the internal cache directory a good place? I will delete the video once it is watermarked and saved to external storage.

Comment: If it fits then internal cache is ok to me.

Comment: Do you have any idea about best practices and size limits related to app's internal storage? @blackapps

Comment: What i think is that when it fits its ok.

Answer (score 0):

All apps (root or not) have a default data directory, which is `/data/data/<package_name>`. By default, the apps databases, settings, and all other data go here

You can find a general explanation of the Android directory hierarchy in my answer here. For your specific question I might add some more details on the `/data/data/<package_name>` (and corresponding SD-part):

- databases/: here go the app's databases
- lib/: libraries and helpers for the app
- files/: other related files
- shared_prefs/: preferences and settings
- cache/: well, caches